# Unlocking a mutex locked by another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

Why does unlocking a mutex which is already kept locked by another thread cause undefined behavior?

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/mutex/unlock/ , if, say, thread 1 locks a mutex, and thread 2 then tries to unlock the same mutex before it is unlocked, we incur in undefined behavior.

Comment: unlocking causes Ub not locking

Comment: Attempting to lock a mutex that's locked by another thread is **exactly** what a mutex is about. That's how you get MUTual EXclusion.

Comment: Sorry, I meant unlocking a locked mutex. I edited my question.

Comment: Answering the "Why?" question, its because unlocking mutex locked by another thread will allow anyone access resources protected by that mutex while still execute code which relies on the fact that it access these resources single-handedly. Thus behavior in such case is undefined.

Comment: In my opinion, this is a matter of "ownership". Unfortunately, nobody here seems to understand that someone might want to pass the lock ownership to other threads. I own a lock and I want to initiate a new thread and pass the lock to it. What is the problem??? I think there should be a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this documentation on the member function `unlock()`, which is the member function whose documentation you are linking: 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock

It states:

> std::mutex::unlock()
>
> Unlocks the mutex.
>
> The mutex must be locked by the current thread of execution,
>   otherwise, **the behavior is undefined**.

So I think the documentation simply states that if a thread tries to unlock a mutex it does not own, we incur in undefined behavior.

For what concerns the title of the question: locking a lock owned by another thread is a well defined behavior (it is why we have `std::mutex`) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock:

> std::mutex::lock()
>
> Locks the mutex. If another thread has already locked the mutex, a
>   call to lock will block execution until the lock is acquired.

As a side note, directly unlocking a mutex is usually a bad idea, you should use RAII wrappers like `std::lock_guard`

Comment: I meant unlocking a locked mutex, I edited the question. My question is not "does it cause ub?", but "why does it cause ub?", i. e. what happens under the hood that causes ub? Is ub unavoidable in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided actually talks about double unlocking, not double locking.
However, the operation (i.e. unlocking the mutex from other thread, while owner thread is not locking it) is UB because the language does not define how a mutex lock should be implemented, thus (and this is pure conjecture) enabling a binary lock, which double unlock might actually lock...

Comment: Edited. I originally meant operation

Comment: There's a more direct route: [thread.mutex.requirements.mutex]/22 says that a call to `m.unlock()` "_Requires:_ The calling thread shall own the mutex", and [res.on.requires]/1 says "Violation of the preconditions specified in a function's _Requires:_ paragraph results in undefined behavior...".

Comment: I meant unlocking a locked mutex, I amended my question. Could you expand more on the possible implementation(s) that could be the root of the problem? That is exactly what I was looking by asking my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/mutex/unlock/:

> All lock and unlock operations on the mutex follow a single total order, with all visible effects synchronized between the lock operations and previous unlock operations on the same object.
>   If the mutex is not currently locked by the calling thread, it causes undefined behavior.

This simply means you should always (in the same thread) call **lock** before **unlock**.

Comment: You should mention that this is a description of the behavior of `mutex::unlock`.